# UNIX ftp command get, change default destination directory

Tags: unix, ftp, get

I know VERY little about UNIX commands, so I´ll do my best to explain what I want in plain English.

Though my mac´s Terminal, I am connected to an ftp account by:

```
ftp example.com
```

When I do:

```
get file.php
```

I download it to the users directory.

So now two related question:

1) How can I choose the download directory for this specific download

and

2) Choose the default destination directory for future download.

Comment: Type `man ftp`, or telnet to the ftp port and type `help` at the daemon. BTW, they’re actually *directories* not *folders*; *folders* is WinSpeak.

Comment: Edited the folder bit :) Im checking out: man ftp Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use a second argument to `get`; e.g. `get file.php path/to/dir/`.
2. Use a command that's usually called `lcd` (for "local change directory"). Not all clients have this command, but most do (for example, [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/), a powerful ftp client, does).